# Simplification of assigning a class to odd elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me in simplifying the below code.

All I am trying to do is replace the "feature-overlay-b" class to "feature-overlay-r" only to odd elements. I tried using ".feature-box:odd" but only the below worked. I would like to avoid adding numbers each time like I did :P

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
if ($(".feature-box")[1]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[1].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[3]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[3].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[5]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[5].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[7]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[7].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[9]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[9].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[11]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[11].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[13]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[13].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[15]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[15].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[17]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[17].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
if ($(".feature-box")[19]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box")[19].childNodes[1].className = "feature-overlay-r";
}
})
</script>


//Sample Loop
<div class="medium-6 large-3 columns feature-box">
        <div class="feature-overlay-b">
            <div class="feature-overlay-container">                 
                <div class="feature-title">Hello World! A</div>
            </div>                
        </div>
</div>

<div class="medium-6 large-3 columns feature-box">
        <div class="feature-overlay-b">
            <div class="feature-overlay-container">                 
                <div class="feature-title">Hello World! B</div>
            </div>                
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: function isOdd(num) { return num % 2;} using this function you can find odd or even number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [odd-selector](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) works fine, see this example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".feature-box:odd").find(".feature-overlay-b").addClass("feature-overlay-r").removeClass("feature-overlay-b");
});
```

```css
.feature-overlay-r {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature-box">
  <div class="feature-overlay-b">
    test
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feature-box">
  <div class="feature-overlay-b">
    test
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feature-box">
  <div class="feature-overlay-b">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: odd works. I just realized I was not looking for the nested elements... @Esko answer is more clear based on my example.

Answer (score 3):

mine `".box:odd"` works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$('.box:odd').toggleClass('odd box');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
<div class="box">s</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var featureElements = $(".feature-box");
    for (var i = 1; i < featureElements.length; i += 2) {
        featureElements[i].addClass("feature-overlay-r")
    }
});
```